# rhc An unexpected error occurred: invalid character at "<!doctype " even direct HIT Enter

Tags: openshift, redhat

I am having issue while setup openshift enviroment, even though I just HIT enter only. Any alternative way to setup?

```
-bash-4.2$ rhc setup
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::NIL is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::Data is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::TRUE is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::FALSE is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::TimeoutError is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace, and check that other programs like Git are properly installed.

If you have your own OpenShift server, you can specify it now. Just hit enter to use the server for OpenShift Online: openshift.redhat.com.
Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com|

You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:746: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:616: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:872: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:746: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:616: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:872: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:983: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:983: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:983: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:983: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
An unexpected error occurred: invalid character at "<!doctype "
```

Answer (score 1):

`rhc` is the command line tool for the deprecated OpenShift v2. If you're looking for the OpenShift v3, built on Kubernetes, command line tool, you can find it here: https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/tag/v3.11.0

If you're trying to use v2 locally for some reason, the openshift.redhat.com server is no longer active, so you would have to specify where you're running a v2 server.